# how to read text files in quanteda, storing each line as a document

Tags: r, nlp, quanteda

I have texts stored in several files.
Within the files each line is a document (text of a blog post, text of a tweet Etc.).
If I read using the readtext package in the default way shown in [doc/examples](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readtext/vignettes/readtext_vignette.html#plain-text-files-.txt) the content of each file will be a single document instead of each line being a document.

My goal is to use a quanteda corpus, with each line stored as a document.
I am using readtext as it is a companion package to quanteda, but using readtext is not a strict requirement.

I would like to avoid manually splitting the originary files in smaller files each corresponding to a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1: use `readLines()` in combination with `list.files()`:

```
txt <- character()
for (f in list.files("your-folder")) {
   txt <- c(txt, readLines(f))
}
corp <- corpus(txt)
```

Method 2: you can split lines in a corpus using `corpus_segment()`:

```
corp <- corpus(readtext("your-folder")) 
corp_line <- corpus_segment(corp, "\n",  extract_pattern = FALSE, pattern_position = "after")
```